# Cropping images with loop in Imagemagick

Tags: linux, image, bash, ubuntu, imagemagick

I'm trying to batch crop images in a folder. Whenever I try doing this loop

```
for image in '/home/donald/Desktop/Im'*.jpg; do 
    convert "$image" -gravity center -crop 95X95% "${image%.jpg}"-modified.jpg
done
```

I end up with the error:

```
convert.im6: unable to open image `/home/donald/Desktop/Im*.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.
convert.im6: no images defined `/home/donald/Desktop/Im*-modified.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044.
```

Which is bizarre because there are definitely images in the folder and according the meta-data they are jpg

When I run `shopt | grep glob` I get this output:

```
dotglob         off
extglob         on
failglob        off
globstar        off
globasciiranges off
nocaseglob      off
nullglob        off
```

Here's my version information:

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Echo $- outputs

```
himBH
```

Comment: Please add output of `shopt  | grep glob` and bash version to your question.

Comment: Done. Is the syntax of my command wrong or is this a problem with my os settings or the imagemagick install?

Comment: Please add output of `echo $-`, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for image in $HOME/Desktop/Im*.jpg; do
   convert "$image" ...
done
```

Another option may be to use the `mogrify` command which is part of the ImageMagick suite:

```
# Create an output directory for cropped images
mkdir cropped
# Crop image and direct output to sub-directory
mogrify -gravity center -crop 95x95% -path cropped  *.jpg
```

You should definitely not parse the output of `ls`.

Answer (score -1):

In the beginning of your for statement, are these quotes or backquotes ?
You must use backquotes.

Try this :

```
for image in `ls -1 /home/donald/Desktop/Im*.jpg`; do 
    convert "$image" -gravity center -crop 95X95% "${image%.*}"-modified.jpg ;
done
```